# How can I access multi dimensional JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I'm trying to access the value of a certain fields of my JSON file.

`console.log( objects.assignments.header.report_type );`

I want to print out `HOMEWORK`

---

## Javascript

```
$.ajax({

      url:  "/BIM/rest/report/assignment",
      type: "POST",
      dataType : "json",
      data: {
        assessmentId: "206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3",
        classroomId:  "722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a"
      },

      success: function( objects ) {

        console.log( objects.assignments.header.report_type );

        // Result : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'report_type' of undefined
```

---

## JSON data - I get back from the AJAX call

```
{
  "assignments": [
    {
      "assignmentId": "SUMMARY",
      "name": "Summary",
      "header": {
        "section_num": "9.4",
        "report_type": "HOMEWORK",
        "problem_set": "Summary",
        "start_time": null,
        "student_am": 0,
        "student_total": 5,
        "due_time": null,
        "submit_am": 0,
        "submit_total": 0,
        "avg_score": "0.0",
        "danger": 0,
        "danger_list": "",
        "warning": 0,
        "warning_list": "",
        "success": 0,
        "success_list": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

How do I access those data properly ?

Any hints / helps on that will mean a lot to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assignments` is an array, so you need to access a specific element.

```
console.log(objects.assignments[0].header.report_type);
                               ^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

$.ajax({

```
  url:  "/BIM/rest/report/assignment",
  type: "POST",
  dataType : "json",
  data: {
    assessmentId: "206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3",
    classroomId:  "722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a"
  },

  success: function( objects ) {

    console.log( objects.assignments[0].header.report_type );
```

Comment: header is an object. It should be header.report_type

Comment: yea...it was in hurry :)

Answer (score 3):

Since `assignments` is an array therefor you must specify an index to access properties inside it. To access use:

```
objects.assignments[0].header.report_type
```

Answer (score 1):

{} means you have a object that has key,value pairs

[] means it is an array that has index (position if you like), value pairs.

```
var myObject = {
    'a_key':'A_value',
    'b_key':'B_value',
    'c_key':'C_value'
    };

var myArray  = [
    'A_value',
    'B_value',
    'C_value'
    ];
```

To access the value of an object you use the key

```
 console.log(myObject.a) // A_value
 console.log(myObject['c']) // C_value
```

values in arrays are available by the index (starting from zero)

```
 console.log(myArray[0]) // A_value
 console.log(myArray[2]) // C_value
```

You can have an array of objects or an object containing some arrays

so in your example it would be:

```
console.log( objects.assignments[0].header.report_type )
             ^           ^       ^    ^        ^
             variable    key   index  key      key
             name        1st lvl      1st lvl  2nd lvl
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple values in your array and want to access them all:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.assignments.length; i++) {
    console.log(objects.assignments[i].header.report_type);
}
```